# Multiple associations in the has_many "through" model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Products` & `Parts` model which would each have multiple uploads, which are also polymorphic.  Is it possible for me to have a single `ItemUpload` model to handle the association between the Products/Parts and Uploads, or do they need to be separate?  I'd try myself just to see, but don't want to cause any potential headaches down the line!  Note that I'm aware I need to do the `source:` and `source_type:` stuff to clean up the polymorphic association with `has_many`, but would like to clarify this point first before proceeding.  Current models:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :uploads, as: :uploadable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :uploads, as: :uploadable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Upload < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :uploadable, polymorphic: true
end
```

What I would ideally like:

```
Class ItemUpload < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
  belongs_to :part, optional: true
  belongs_to :upload
end
```

Is that ok or would I need a separate `ProductUpload` and `PartUpload` model?

Comment: Why do you need a separate `upload` and `item_upload`?

Comment: Because each `upload` should theoretically be able to belong to both a `product` and a `part` at the same time, or multiple `products` and `parts` at the same time.  `uploadable` only supports a single one or the other, correct?

Comment: Yeah, ok, since upload and product / upload and part are HABTM or HMT relationships I'm not seeing this as calling for polymorphic.  The join table could be polymorphic but it just seems you're making it very difficult to make `upload.products` and `upload.parts` methods. Polymorphic is useful for associating records to multiple classes but it's not always appropriate. Go for `ProductUpload` and `PartsUpload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought your associations would look more like:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_uploads, as: :itemable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :uploads, through: :item_uploads
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_uploads, as: :itemable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :uploads, through: :item_uploads
end

class Upload < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_uploads
  has_many :products, through: :item_uploads, source: :itemable, source_type: 'Product'
  has_many :parts, through: :item_uploads, source: :itemable, source_type: 'Part'
end

Class ItemUpload < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :itemable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :upload
end
```

That should allow you to do:

```
product.uploads
part.uploads
upload.products
upload.parts
```

BTW, in reference to the link you provided:

```
Upload        ≈ User
ItemUpload    ≈ Membership
Product, Part ≈ Project, Group
```

The above follows the pattern in the linked article.

Comment: Ok, I hadn't even considered going that route!  A couple things; does this negate me having to go through the hassle of tying together the polymorphic association with the has_many association, like the solution in this example? https://medium.com/code2-blog/polymorphic-has-many-through-associations-in-ruby-on-rails-97778e1cea1a

Comment: Adding another comment here because I am now realizing this might not work for my situation.  `ItemUpload` would only allow one Upload and either one Part or Product.  I theoretically need a single upload to be able to belong to multiple products and multiple parts at the same time.  Or can I have multiple `ItemUploads` with the same Upload ID?